# AVR C compilers behavior. Memory management

Tags: c, compiler-construction, microcontroller, avr, ram

Do AVR C compilers make program memorize the address in SRAM where function started to store its data (variables, arrays) in data stack in one of index registers in order to get absolute address of local variable by formula:

```
absoluteAdr = functionDataStartAdr + localShiftOfVariable.
```

And do they increase data stack point when variable declared by it's length or stack pointer increased in end/start of function for all it's variables lengths.

Comment: what happened when you tried it?  what did your compiler do?

Comment: @old_timer Mine compiler can make staic variables, conditions, unions, gotos, arithmetic opertions. I just want to take a look how professional compilers deal whis functions(how do they mamage the SRAM memory)

Comment: that is what I meant, go try one, I assumed you already have gcc or one of the other free/trial ones...

Comment: we know the answer btw it is yes and know, your question is a bit vague, and I understand the language barrier and that is fine.  obviously the compiler has to generate code that can address/access the variable.  Sometimes the variable is optimized into a register, sometimes the address.  sometimes it is pc relative sometimes it is absolute.  and a lot has to do with what the architecture offers then what the compiler author(s) chooses.

Comment: when the item is on the stack it is often by reference, particularly with C, the stack pointer or a frame pointer with some offset, so yes a base plus an offset provides an absolute.  pc relative is the pc plus an offset provides an absolute.  And for globals or static locals usually the compiler leaves a pc relative location (talking in general here apply this to AVR or other as needed) which the linker fills in later with the absolute address.  And if you offer position independent code (PIC) then you play more games

Comment: Sometimes a variable is even ending up in a register that has an address (which can be even more confusing)  - AVR gcc is a bit special in that it seems to address registers both as registers and as memory (in the AVR register file)

Comment: There is no question in this question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's have a look at avr-gcc, which is freely available including [its ABI](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/avr-gcc#ABI):

> Do AVR C compilers make program memorize the address in SRAM where function started to store its data (variables, arrays) in data stack in one of index registers in order to get absolute address of local variable by formula:

Yes, no, it depends:

**Static Storage**

For variables in static storage, i.e. variables as defined by

```
unsigned char func (void)
{
    static unsigned char var;
    return ++var;
}
```

the compiler generates a symbol like `var.123` with appropriate size (1 byte in this case).  The linker / locator will then assign the address.

```
func:
    lds  r24,var.1505
    subi r24,lo8(-(1))
    sts  var.1505,r24
    ret
    .local  var.1505
    .comm   var.1505,1,1
```

**Automatic**

Automatic variables are held in registers if possible, otherwise the compiler allocates space in the frame of the function.  It may even be the case that variables are optimized out, and in that case they do not exist anywhere in the program:

```c
int add (void)
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    return a + b;
}
```

→

```
add:
    ldi r24,lo8(3)
    ldi r25,0
    ret
```

There are 3 types of entities that are stored in the frame of a function, all of which might be present or absent depending on the program:

- Callee-saved registers that are saved (PUSH'ed) by the function prologue and restored (POP'ed) by the epilogue.  This is needed when local variables are allocated to callee-saved registers.
- Space for local variables that cannot be allocated to registers.  This happens when the variable is too big to be held in registers, there are too many auto variables, or the address of a variable is taken (and taking the address cannot be optimized out).  This is because you cannot take the address of a register<sup>1</sup>.

  ```c
  void use_address (int*);

  void func (void)
  {
     int a;
     use_address (&a);
  }
  ```

  The space for these variables is allocated in the prologue and deallocated in the epilogue.  Shrink-wrapping is not implemented:

  ```
  func:
      push r28
      push r29
      rcall .
      in r28,__SP_L__
      in r29,__SP_H__
      /* prologue: function */
      /* frame size = 2 */
      /* stack size = 4 */
      movw r24,r28
      adiw r24,1
      rcall use_address
      pop __tmp_reg__
      pop __tmp_reg__
      pop r29
      pop r28
      ret
  ```

  In this example, `a` occupies 2 bytes which are allocated by `rcall .` (it was compiled for a device with 16-bit program counter).  Then the compiler initialized the frame-pointer `Y` (R29:R28) with the value of the stack pointer.  This is needed because on AVR, you cannot access memory via SP; the only memory operations that involve SP are `PUSH` and `POP`. Then the address of that variable which is `Y+1` is passed in `R24`.  After the call of the function, the epilogue frees the frame and restores R28 and R29.
- Arguments that have to be passed on the stack:

  ```
  void xfunc (int, ...);

  void call_xfunc (void)
  {
      xfunc (42);
  }
  ```

  These arguments are pushed and the callee is picking them up from the stack.  These arguments are pushed / popped around the call, but can also be accumulated by means of `-maccumulate-args`.

  ```
  call_func:
      push __zero_reg__
      ldi r24,lo8(42)
      push r24
      rcall xfunc
      pop __tmp_reg__
      pop __tmp_reg__
      ret
  ```

  In this example, the argument has to be passed on the stack because the ABI says that all arguments of a varargs function have to be passed on the stack, including the named ones.

For a description on how exactly the frame is being layed out and arguments are being passed, see [Frame Layout and Argument Passing] (https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/avr-gcc#Frame_Layout).

<sup>1</sup> Some AVRs actually allow this, but you never (like in NEVER) want to pass around the address of a general purpose register!

Answer (score 1):

Compilers are not managing the RAM, compilers at compilation time calculate the required size for each data sections like bss, data, text, rodata, .. etc and generate relocatable object file for each translation unit

The linker comes after and generate one object file and assign the relocatable addresses to absolute ones mapped according to the Linker configuration File LCF.

In run time, the mechanism depends on the architecture itself. normally, each function call has a frame in the stack where it's arguments, return address and local variables are defined. the stack extend with a creation of variables and for low cost AVR microcontrollers, there is no memory management protection regarding the stack increase or the overlapping between the stack and another memory section -normally the heap-. even if there is OS managing the protection from the tasks to exceed its allocated stack, without a memory management unit, all what OS can do is to assert a **RESET** with illegal memory access reason.

Comment: This answer is incorrect on a number of important details -- for example, a linker does not "assign the virtual addresses to physical addresses" even in environments where such a distinction exists. (AVR does not use virtual addressing at all.) Moreover, you don't seem to be answering the question.

Comment: i mean by virtual addressing is that the compiler doesn't allocate the physical absolute addresses for data section, it's the job of the linker
the linker is responsible for setting absolute addresses for different data section based on LCF, see the following [link]https://blog.feabhas.com/2012/06/the-c-build-process/

Comment: That's not what the term "virtual addressing" means. This terminology is used in reference to systems which use a MMU to implement virtual memory. AVR is not such a system.